# Does glClear have a high impact on fill rate?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am using multisampling in iPhone openGL ES project. Just using the glClear command causes the renderer utilization to go upto almost 42%. Is this the way its supposed to be or am I doing something wrong? I am using an iPod Touch 4th generation for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the renderer utilisation goes to ~42% in a render that consists of your scene + the clear compared to a render that just consists of your scene?

glClear() is a very efficient operation on PowerVR GPUs as the clear is done on a tile as it's processed by the GPU. The only case I can think of where an overhead would be introduced by a clear is if you're tests only consist of a clear and a swap each frame compared to just a swap (where GPU work would be optimised out).

[Apple's online documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html) gives some insight into how glClear is interpreted by their graphics driver.

If you want to know more about the PowerVR architecture and how operations like glClear() are processed, I would also recommend reading "SGX Architecture Guide for Developers" & "PowerVR Performance Recommendations" on Imagination's [documentation page](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-sdk-docs.asp).

Comment: no. it goes to 42% utilization with just the glClearColor and glClear command and all of my other drawing code commented out. Is glClear the same as rendering a full screen  rectangle with a fill color?

Comment: Ah, ok. As mentioned above, a render with no work will be optimized out. You're seeing increased renderer workload because the GPU has been told to process a clear (which is very cheap, but certainly more expensive than rendering nothing at all).

It's not a full screen quad. When glClear is called, flags are passed to the GPU that indicate which buffers should be cleared (an optimized path).

On PowerVR GPUs, you should always glClear unless you need to preserve the previous render. The flag also indicates that the previous image does not need to be uploaded to the GPU.

Comment: so is it normal to get such a high utilization when using multisampling. If I turn off multi-sampling it goes down to about 18% with just glClear() and no other drawing code.

Comment: That sounds normal to me. The cost is a baseline for processing anything - even something as simple as a clear. If you add a few draw calls to your render, I'd expect the performance to be about the same.

Comment: My own testing showed a significant performance hit if glClear() was invoked, it runs faster when you do no call glClear(). This was using GLKit in a view and OpenGL ES 2.0. The Profiler tools claim performance is better if you call glClear(), but that does not seem to be the case using GLKit under iOS.